# Not able to refresh Lightning data-table repeatedly, with refreshApex inside setInterval()

Tags: lightning-datatable

In Chrome's inspect, I could see the "interval run!" being repeated, but the data-table doesn't refresh. New data only display when I manually refresh the entire page.

```
   refresh() {
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log("interval run!");
            return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
          }, 2000);
    }
```

Src:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getLog from '@salesforce/apex/FridgeLogsController.getLog';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';


const columns = [
    {label: 'Timestamp', fieldName: 'LastModifiedDate', type: 'date',
        typeAttributes:{
            weekday: "long",
            year: "numeric",
            month: "long",
            day: "2-digit",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit"
        }
    },
    {label: 'Employee Name', fieldName: 'employeeName__c', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Fridge ID', fieldName: 'fridgeId__c', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Phone #', fieldName: 'contactPhone', type: 'phone'},
];

export default class ExerciseTrigger extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;
    refreshTable;
    @track log;

    refresh() {
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log("interval run!");
            return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
          }, 2000);
    }
    
    connectedCallback() {  
        this.refresh();
        console.log("connectedcallback ran");
    }  

    @wire(getLog) logList(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.refreshTable = result;
            this.error = undefined;

            let preparedArr = [];
            result.data.forEach(record => {
                let preparedRec = {};
                preparedRec.Id = record.Id;
                preparedRec.date = record.LastModifiedDate;
                preparedRec.LastModifiedDate = record.LastModifiedDate;
                preparedRec.employeeName__c = record.employeeName__c;
                preparedRec.fridgeId__c = record.fridgeId__c;
                preparedRec.contactPhone = record.Contact__r.Phone;

                preparedArr.push(preparedRec);
            });
            this.log = [...preparedArr];
            
        } else if (result.data) {
            this.log = result.error;
            this.error = undefined;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant to this specific problem but the else if in your logList wire handler is wrong; should be checking result.error. Also regardless of success or which properties exist in the result, this should update the refreshTable property.

Comment: The problem is because you have used a function, not arrow function, for setting up the timeout callback. That means the "this" pointer is no longer the component.

Comment: @PhilW Solved - arrow function works thanks!